# Sympy define function of the upper limit of an integral

Tags: python, function, sympy, integral

Using Sympy, I would like to define a function of one variable where the variable is the upper limit of some integral.

I tried the following, which works

```
import sympy as sp

def g(a,x):
    y = sp.Symbol('y')
    expr = sp.Integral( f(y,p), [y,a,x] )
    return expr.doit()
```

However, I ask myself if this is gonna be efficient when evaluated on many points. I have been reading about lambdify and would like to use it for this case, but am not sure how.

I am actually not sure if lambdify is the right way to go. In alternative, one could think of computing the indefinite integral once, and then only apply the limits to evaluate the definite integral.

Let me show an example. I have a function of one variable with some parameters, say a polynomial in y

```
def f(y, p):
    c0,c1,c2=p
    return c0+c1*y+c2*y**2
```

I want to define another function by integrating this polynomial, where the function is going to depend on the upper limit of the integration (Latex because I don't have enough reputation...),

g_{a,p}(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(y,p)dy

So, in this simple case, g(x) would be polynomial or order 3 which needs to be evaluated between a and x. Once I have g(x), I want to evaluate it on "many" points, so my question is if I can do this efficiently.

I made a naive implementation of the solution and one using sympy.lambdify. Only timed it once, so not the most accurate results. However, using sympy.lambdify seems 100x faster.

### Naive implementation

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import time

def f(y, p):
    c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 = p
    return c0 + c1*x + c2*x**2 + c3*x**3 + c4*x**4 + c5*x**5

def g(a,x):
    y = sp.Symbol('y')
    expr = sp.Integral( f(y,p), [y,a,x] )
    return expr.doit()

start = time.clock()
l = []
for x in np.arange(a,b,0.001):
    l.append(g(a,x))
end = time.clock()
print end-start
```

### Improved implementation

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import time

def f(y, p):
    c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 = p
    return c0 + c1*x + c2*x**2 + c3*x**3 + c4*x**4 + c5*x**5

x=sp.Symbol('x')
itgx = sp.Integral( f(y,p), [y,a, x] )
start = time.clock()
g = sp.lambdify(x, itgx.doit(), "numpy")
l = g(np.arange(a,b,0.001))
end = time.clock()
print end-start
```

On my architecture (i7-3770 @3.40GHz, Ubuntu 14.04),
the naive implementation times 12.086627s while the lambdify implementation times 0.054799s, that looks like a significant speed up. Sympy manual also suggests to use lambdify when possible

So my question, which maybe is not clear enough, is:
**Is there a better way of doing this kind of computation?** If so, please let me know

Comment: Could you give an actual example!? Also, the parameter p is not defined. What is the function of your variable y?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the lambdified version is faster. Not only is it vectorizing the result over a numpy array rather than using a Python `for` loop, you're also being very inefficient in the other version by **recomputing the integral each time**.

I don't see an actual question here. Your lambdified version looks correct. I don't see any issues with it.

Comment: yeah so that's what I thought too and exactly the reason why I was asking for other ideas. I know that the solutions I wrote are correct and that one is of course faster, but I asked if there are other or better ways to do this. I don't see an actual answer to this question here...

Comment: Your "improved" version looks fine to me. As far as SymPy usage goes, I don't see any points of improvement.

Comment: If you are still having performance issues, I would recommend looking into SymPy's code generation module (such as `autowrap` or `ufuncify`). Another option would be to wrap your lambdified function with `numba.jit`.